# Javascript Publisher/Subscriber Pattern Example

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, publish-subscribe

I'm learning Publisher/subscriber pattern and have done a simple example to understand it better.

```
var Publisher = {
    subscribers: {},       
    Subscribe: function (event, callback) {
        if (Publisher[event] && typeof callback === "function") {
            if (Publisher.subscribers[event]) {
                Publisher.subscribers[event].callbacks.push(callback);
            }
            else {
                Publisher.subscribers[event] = { callbacks: [callback] };
            }
        }
    },
    Publish: function (event) {
        if (Publisher.subscribers[event].callbacks) {
            for (callback in Publisher.subscribers[event].callbacks) {
                Publisher.subscribers[event].callbacks[callback].apply(null);
            }
        }
    },

    PublishOnClick: function (event, argument) {
        Publisher.Publish(event, argument);
    }
};

var Subscriber1 = {
    initialize: function () {
        if (Publisher.Subscribe) {
            Publisher.Subscribe("PublishOnClick", Subscriber1.Action);
        }
    },
    Action: function (c) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += "Button Clicked and the count is: " + c;
        c++;
    }
};
Subscriber1.initialize();


var c = 1;
var fld2 = document.getElementById("myfield2");
if (fld2.addEventListener) {
    fld2.addEventListener("click", function() { Publisher.PublishOnClick("PublishOnClick", [c]); }, false);
} else if (fld2.attachEvent) {
    fld2.attachEvent("onclick", function() { Publisher.PublishOnClick("PublishOnClick", [c]); });
}
```

I have a button and partial view, and im trying to raise an event through button and display the count on a partial view. Im getting the event rasied and shown on the partial view, but only problem is with the count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't actually with the publisher-subscriber paradigm, from what I see.

Your setup is a little ...convoluted, I suppose, as it might be easier to grasp from the standpoint of something like:

```
twitter_feed.tweets = [];
twitter_feed.root_el = document.getElementById("tweets");
twitter_feed.update = function (tweet) {
    twitter_feed.tweets.push(tweet);
    // demonstration-purposes only -- please don't write live code like this
    twitter_feed.root_el.innerHTML += "<p>" + tweet.user + ": \"" + tweet.text + "\"</p>";
};


twitter_data.subscribe("new-tweet", twitter_feed.update);

// some event handler which grabs tweets from AJAX or whatever...
twitter_data.notify("new-tweet", { user : "Me", text : "my new tweet" });
```

The goal being that a publisher isn't THE object, but rather where there is an object which CAN publish data, and a subscriber isn't THE object, but rather is an extension of an object which can react to published events...

...anyway, your code works for the paradigm at hand...

...except:

```
Action : function (c) { /* ... */ c++; }
```

The problem is that JS ***passes SCALAR data by VALUE and NOT by REFERENCE***.

So in your function, when it's being called, you aren't passing:

```
// .Action(c);
Action (reference_to_c) {
    /*...*/.innerHTML = reference_to_c;
    reference_to_c++;
}
```

You're actually passing:

```
// .Action(c);
Action (1) {
    /*...*/.innerHTML = 1;
    1++;
};
```

Objects in JS are passed by reference. "Objects" includes functions and arrays.
Non-object scalars (`number`s, `string`s, `boolean`s, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`) are passed by value, so if you have a function-parameter where the argument is a scalar, editing the version inside of the function won't change the value outside.

```
var x = 1,
    say_X = function (x) { x += 1; console.log(x); };

say_X(x); // 2;
console.log(x); // 1;

// vs
var obj = { x : 1 },
    say_X = function (o) { o.x += 1; console.log(o.x); };

say_X(obj); // 2;
console.log(obj.x); //2;
```

What you'd really want to do here is have the publisher keep track of the count, OR have the subscriber keep track of the count, depending on where it would make sense to do so.
Have a look at my Twitter example, up top.

It would make sense for the `twitter_feed` to keep track of all of the tweets it prints to the screen, so that when a new tweet comes in, it gets added to the list.
The latest `twitter_data` wouldn't care about previous tweets, so in that case, the subscriber would be keeping track of state, and the publisher would just be listening for changes and notifying others when something happens.

In other cases, it might make sense for the publisher to keep track of its state, and announce new state to the subscribers:

```
music_playlist.update_track = function (data) {
     music_playlist.current_song.innerHTML = data.current_song;
};
music_player.subscribe("song-change", music_playlist.update_track);
music_player.notify("song-change", { current_song: "Sympathy for the Daleks" });
```

In this case, the playlist only really cares about updating the title that the user sees on the page.
The music player is handling which song is currently available and what state it's currently in, and all of that other good stuff.

So the solution to your current problem is one of the following:

1. Make `c` a property of Publisher, which adds to c and notifies its subscribers afterward
2. Make `c` a property of Subscriber, where every time Publisher notifies Subscriber, it adds to its own `c` property, and then writes it out
3. Take `c` out of the parameters of `Action` (to look like `Action : function () { /*...*/ }`, so that the `c` inside of the function will point to `window.c` ...sloppy, but works.

Any of those three should fix your issue.